# 502 Bad Gateway on high traffic

Tags: nginx, 502-error

When my website receives **many** requests per second (I assume at least 80 requests per second), the server randomly blocks some requests with `502 Bad Gateway nginx`-errors. This happens every few seconds: All requests are blocked and you can't even view the website after a quick refresh. But then again, three seconds later, everything is back to normal.
The site is in general very fast, even during these weird phases. It doesn't lag or anything - it just randomly blocks connections.

The error messages seem to appear for everyone at the same time. So I assume that there is some kind of timed max_connection limit or something which quits the service for a few seconds.

I've tried everything that came up to my mind:

Checking `ulimits` (Soft & Hard are both at about 50,000),
nginx worker_connections raised to 8,192 (from 4,094) 
and doubled `max_connections` in my mysql settings.

Still without any effect.
Also I tried to look through every error log on my server (nginx, httpd, mysql etc.), but I couldn't find anything useful. Though maybe I'm missing an important log... they're quiet hard to find and I don't really know what to look for.

Is there anything I could try?
I can also provide several `.conf` files, if necessary.

Comment: What is the complete application stack?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm using PHP, MySQL, Apache, nginx, fastcgi...

Comment: Have you taken a look at PHP-FPM's log file? It most likely tells you that all worker pools are busy, and that is the reason for 503 errors.

Comment: Uff, well, I've been looking for this log file now, though I can't find it. I can't even find a configuarition file for PHP-FPM to see/change/set the log directory.. Google doesn't really help there

Comment: I actually never heard of PHP-FPM before. Might it be that I don't have it installed on my server?

Comment: Really? Who installed this?

Comment: You're probably proxying through nginx to apache? Apache gives an error or timeout which triggers the bad gateway, is my guess.

Comment: Micheal: The server hosting company did.

Comment: wurtel: This sounds about right. Any guessing though on how I could fix it?